# AWS autoscaling and spot instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, autoscaling

I am working on my small project and using mix of spot and on-demand instances. I need to setup autoscaling to launch spot instances in different AZ only.
For example, the desired number of instances is 3 and we have 4 AZ where they might be placed. Autoscaling tries to place the instances in different AZ but if it fails, it launches them in the same AZ, which is something I don't want.

I'd like to use another logic. If Autoscaling is not able to place all spot instances in different AZ, it starts launching on-demand ones instead. Is it possible to setup with tools that we have?

I want to avoid the situation where a few spot instances will end up in the same AZ because if the AZ capacity goes down, amazon terminates them quickly and I will not have any time to relaunch them somewhere else.

Comment: Are you using launch templates? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-purchase-options.html Using launch templates instead of launch configurations with an autoscaling group will provide the desired behavior

Comment: No, it won't. A template let me specify preset balance between spot and on-demand instances but it does not make autoscaling try to use spot instances first and if it's not possible use on-demand ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid spot instances losing capacity, then a good strategy is:

- Use a **mix of Instance Types:** If spot instances of one type are terminated due to low capacity, then it is unlikely that other instance types will be impacted at the same time
- Spread the instances **across Availability Zones** (as you are doing), since capacity pools are separate in each AZ

**Auto Scaling** will automatically attempt to balance the number of EC2 instances across Availability Zones. Auto Scaling can only have one active Launch Configuration or Launch Template at any one time. Therefore, it cannot automatically switch between on-demand and spot instances.

You might want to look into [Launching an EC2 Fleet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-fleet.html), which can automatically launch a range of different instance types across multiple Availability Zones. There are also some recommended [EC2 Fleet Configuration Strategies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-fleet-configuration-strategies.html).

Comment: I'd like to apply the logic where autoscaling will use spot instances first and if it failed, try to use on-demand ones.

Comment: Is there any way to restrict autoscaling to launch instances in the same AZ? I am totally fine with not launching instance at all if it's not possible to put them all in different AZs.

Comment: Auto Scaling does not have the ability to use spot and, if it fails, use on-demand. You would need to do additional coding (somehow) to make that happen. Auto Scaling will always try to put instances in separate AZs if possible. You cannot change this behaviour.

Comment: John Rotenstein, Fair enough. I expected that Amazon would not provide tools to let thier customers save money :))))) Now I am thinking how to code this feature.

Comment: On the contrary, there are many tools provided for saving money, such as Spot Instances, Trusted Advisor and Auto Scaling itself (scale-in when capacity not required). However, an Auto Scaling can only have one configuration at a time.

Comment: @Samuel Did you find solution for ```I'd like to apply the logic where autoscaling will use spot instances first and if it failed, try to use on-demand ones.```? Please let me know. Thanks